# Custom query fields dropped by rails 3 model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to do a group_by query and pass along a count for each of the grouped rows returned. However, my count column doesn't appear in the results. I believe the model is dropping the column because I don't have an attr_accessor for it. I tried adding the dynamic count column as an attr_accessor and attr_accessible, but I still am not able to keep this count column.

Here's my query:

`organization = Organization.last`

`referrals = Invitations.recently_invited.select("COUNT(*) as referrals, invitations.*").where("invitee_id IN (?)", organization.map{|m| m.contact.id}).group(:event_id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Invitations.recently_invited.select("invitations.*").where("invitee_id IN (?)", organization.map{|m| m.contact.id}).group(:event_id).count
```

Comment: Thanks! That looks like it gives me something I can play with.

Comment: double check the query make sure the ids are separated by commas

Comment: Good call. I'll check that. Thanks again. The hash returned is exactly what I need.